# Compare two dictionary and filter

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I have dictionary1 that contains

```
{'A': Timestamp('2022-05-23 00:00:00'), 'L': Timestamp('2017-06-21 00:00:00'), 'S': Timestamp('2021-11-02 00:00:00'), 'D': Timestamp('2021-11-08 00:00:00')}
```

Then I have another dictionary2 that looks like

```
{'A': [Timestamp('2022-01-16 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-01-13 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-01-12 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2023-01-10 00:00:00')],
'L': [Timestamp('2023-01-16 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2023-01-13 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2023-01-12 00:00:00')],
'S': [Timestamp('2021-01-16 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-01-13 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2023-01-12 00:00:00')],
 'D': [Timestamp('2023-01-16 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-10-18 00:00:00')]}
```

I would like to have for each `A, L, S, D`  only those dates that are **GREATER** than those dates in dictionary1

So my desired output would be

```
{'A': [Timestamp('2023-01-10 00:00:00')],
'L': [Timestamp('2023-01-16 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2023-01-13 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2023-01-12 00:00:00')],
'S': [Timestamp('2022-01-13 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2023-01-12 00:00:00')],
 'D': [Timestamp('2023-01-16 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-10-18 00:00:00')]}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `pandas` are you looking for a pandas solution - i.e., converting things to a pandas.DataFrame?

Comment: Yes, i thought it can be easier with `pandas`  and to have eventually a converted dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pandas solution

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

d1 = {'A': Timestamp('2022-05-23 00:00:00'),
      'L': Timestamp('2017-06-21 00:00:00'),
      'S': Timestamp('2021-11-02 00:00:00'),
      'D': Timestamp('2021-11-08 00:00:00')}

d2 = {'A': [Timestamp('2022-01-16 00:00:00'),
            Timestamp('2022-01-13 00:00:00'),
            Timestamp('2022-01-12 00:00:00'),
            Timestamp('2023-01-10 00:00:00')],
      'L': [Timestamp('2023-01-16 00:00:00'),
            Timestamp('2023-01-13 00:00:00'),
            Timestamp('2023-01-12 00:00:00')],
      'S': [Timestamp('2021-01-16 00:00:00'),
            Timestamp('2022-01-13 00:00:00'),
            Timestamp('2023-01-12 00:00:00')],
      'D': [Timestamp('2023-01-16 00:00:00'),
            Timestamp('2022-10-18 00:00:00')]}

# convert to a series and explode lists
s1 = pd.Series(d1, name='date')
s2 = pd.Series(d2, name='date').explode()
# merge your pd.Series together on the index
m = pd.merge(s2, s1, right_index=True, left_index=True, how='left')
# boolean indexing to filter your dates where s2 date > s1 date
new_df = m[m['date_x'] > m['date_y']]

      date_x     date_y
A 2023-01-10 2022-05-23
D 2023-01-16 2021-11-08
D 2022-10-18 2021-11-08
L 2023-01-16 2017-06-21
L 2023-01-13 2017-06-21
L 2023-01-12 2017-06-21
S 2022-01-13 2021-11-02
S 2023-01-12 2021-11-02
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your two data sources you might use a comprehension to create a new list based on the criteria:

```py
import datetime

Timestamp = lambda s: datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S")

lookup = {
    'A': Timestamp('2022-05-23 00:00:00'),
    'L': Timestamp('2017-06-21 00:00:00'),
    'S': Timestamp('2021-11-02 00:00:00'),
    'D': Timestamp('2021-11-08 00:00:00')
}

data_in = {
    'A': [
        Timestamp('2023-01-10 00:00:00')
    ],
    'L': [
        Timestamp('2023-01-16 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2023-01-13 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2023-01-12 00:00:00')
    ],
    'S': [
        Timestamp('2022-01-13 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2023-01-12 00:00:00')
    ],
    'D': [
        Timestamp('2023-01-16 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2022-10-18 00:00:00')
    ]
}

data_out = [
    {key: [v for v in value if v > lookup[key]]}
    for key, value
    in data_in.items()
]

print(data_out)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `Timestamp` is, but if it has a function that returns the dates as a string (or any other data structure with a `>` defined), you can do

```
# This is some class that knows its stamp value (the "date")
class Timestamp:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    def __init__(self, value):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        self._value = value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    @property                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    def value(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        return self._value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
# This is your reference dict.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
d1 = {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    'A': Timestamp('2022-05-23 00:00:00'),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    'L': Timestamp('2017-06-21 00:00:00'),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    'S': Timestamp('2021-11-02 00:00:00'),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    'D': Timestamp('2021-11-08 00:00:00')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
}

# This is the data you want to clean.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
d2 = {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    'A': [                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        Timestamp('2022-01-16 00:00:00'),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        Timestamp('2022-01-13 00:00:00'),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        Timestamp('2022-01-12 00:00:00'),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        Timestamp('2023-01-10 00:00:00')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    ],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    'L': [                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        Timestamp('2023-01-16 00:00:00'),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        Timestamp('2023-01-13 00:00:00'),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        Timestamp('2023-01-12 00:00:00')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    ],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    'S': [                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        Timestamp('2021-01-16 00:00:00'),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        Timestamp('2022-01-13 00:00:00'),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        Timestamp('2023-01-12 00:00:00')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    ],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    'D': [Timestamp('2023-01-16 00:00:00'),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
          Timestamp('2022-10-18 00:00:00')]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
# This is the new dict you want.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
d3 = {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    key: [stamp for stamp in stamplist if stamp.value > d1[key].value]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    for (key, stamplist) in d2.items()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
# Check it:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
for key, stamplist in d3.items():                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    for stamp in stamplist:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        print(stamp.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

With [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), one way is to use [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) constructor with a *dict/listcomp* :

```
from pandas import Timestamp

s1 = pd.Series(dictionary1)
s2 = pd.Series(dictionary2)
​
out = {k: [v for v in s2[k] if k > s1[k]] for k in s2.index}
```

Output :
​

```
   {'A': [Timestamp('2023-01-10 00:00:00')],
    'L': [Timestamp('2023-01-16 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2023-01-13 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2023-01-12 00:00:00')],
    'S': [Timestamp('2022-01-13 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2023-01-12 00:00:00')],
    'D': [Timestamp('2023-01-16 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-10-18 00:00:00')]}
```